# Creating sheets with from master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

1. I have a sheet named form responses which gets input from google
   forms,Then I created sheets with names from Column C which is
   employee code and append all the respective rows from form responses
   to the newly created sheets.
2. Now I have sheets with name as employee code ( which is in column c of the sheet). Then I want to create secondary sheets from this master sheet(sheets with name as employee code) whose name is using the column E value as attached to the    Employee code.for eg : if Emp code is 10003825 and value in column E is ASR, the sheet name should be 10001515ASR.
3. In Column E there are only 4 values ADC,ASR ACC,RSR. let the master sheet(sheets with name as employee code) retain ADC rows always while when other rows containing ASR,ACC,RSR comes append the respective row to the newly created sheet(ie if ASR the row goes to 10001515ASR).
4. I have shown my present sheet and expected output

The code  I developed is shown below:

```
 function switchSheet(){
    var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheets = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets();
    for (var i = 1; i < sheets.length; i++) {
       var p =  sheets[i].getSheetName();
       sheetCreateChannel(p);
      }
    }
 function sheetCreateChannel(ss){
   var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet1 = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(ss);
   var getNames = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
   getNames.shift();
   var sheets = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets();
   var sheetsObj = {};
      for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
       sheetsObj[sheets[i].getSheetName()] = sheets[i];
       for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
         var r = getNames[i];
         if (r[4].toString()== "ASR"&& !((ss+(r[4])) in sheetsObj)) {
                    var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(ss + "ASR");
                    sheetsObj[ss+"ASR"] = newSheet;
                   }
         else if (r[4].toString()== "ACC"&&!((ss+(r[4])) in sheetsObj)) {
              var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(ss + "ACC");
              sheetsObj[ss+"ACC"] = newSheet;
                   }
         else if (r[4].toString()== "RSR"&& !((ss+(r[4])) in sheetsObj)) {
              var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet(ss + "RSR");
              sheetsObj[ss+"RSR"] = newSheet;
              }
         else  {
              break;
              }
            }
           } 
         var deleteRows = 0;
           for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
            var r = getNames[i];
             if (r[4].toString() != "") {
              if ((ss+(r[4])) in sheetsObj) {
               var Q =ss+(r[4]);
                sheetsObj[Q].appendRow(r);
             } 
          deleteRows = i + 2;
          }    
         }
        sheet1.getRange(2, 1, deleteRows - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
       }
```

[image: Screen shot of my present sheet]

[image: The expected output]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: @Tanaike I have created a sheet from my master sheet using column C value. Now I want to create a sheet using the sheets created using column C as master sheet. I have attached a screenshot of my sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, from your replying and updating question, I cannot still understand about your current issue and goal. I apologize for this. Can you give me a time to understand about them?

Comment: My English is pretty good, but I don't understand the request either. You state you want a sheet name to be the EmployeeID + column E. Okay... what's the problem? You'll probably run into some duplicate sheet names. If you were able to execute your code correctly, what would it look like? Perhaps share a sample file?

Comment: @Tanaike  The issue is I have to create sheets from secondary sheet for eg here 10001515 sheet to create sheets 10001515ASR,10001515ACC,10001515RSR  but not 10001515ADC. then append all the rows relevent to ASR in 10001515 to 10001515ASR and so on, but for all rows relevent to ADC let those rows remain in 10001515.whenever the master sheet is updated this sheet also get updated when the code is ran and it should not create 10001515ASRASR like as  I am getting error  like this everytime updation happens

Comment: Can you please edit your question with all the relevant information? Are there more than one Sheet? More than one Spreadsheet? Where are you running the script from? Where is the information coming from?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I have edited the question the task is from second point .

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating this. Can you not just go down column C, concatenate the contents with the cell in column E for the same row, then create a new sheet? And do that for all rows?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I didn't understand your logic. can you tell me with a example code.

Comment: I think you need to explain your logic more clearly. I'm not writing code for you that I'm not even sure you want. What are the sheets you want generating, how many do you want, where is the information coming from for the names of them?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I got your logic the program now works fine after concatenation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine for my above issue

```
 function sheetCreate(){
   var activeSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var sheet1 = activeSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
   var getNames = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
   getNames.shift();
   var sheets = activeSpreadsheet.getSheets();
   var sheetsObj = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
     sheetsObj[sheets[i].getSheetName()] = sheets[i];
     }
   var deleteRows = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < getNames.length; i++) {
     var r = getNames[i];
     var N=r[2].toString()+r[4].toString(); 
        if (N != "") {
         if (N in sheetsObj) {
          sheetsObj[N].appendRow(r);
        } else {
          var newSheet = activeSpreadsheet.insertSheet((N));
          var cell1 = newSheet.getRange("A1").setValue("Timestamp");
          var cell2 = newSheet.getRange("B1").setValue("Score");
          var cell3 = newSheet.getRange("C1").setValue("Employee ID");
          var cell4 = newSheet.getRange("D1").setValue("Name of the ATCO");
          var cell5 = newSheet.getRange("E1").setValue("The channel on which duty is performed ");
          var cell6 = newSheet.getRange("F1").setValue("DATE on which duty  is performed");
          var cell7 = newSheet.getRange("G1").setValue("Total duration of duty done");
          newSheet.appendRow(r);
          sheetsObj[N] = newSheet;
          }
        deleteRows = i + 2;
        }    
       }
      sheet1.getRange(2, 1, deleteRows - 1, sheet1.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
     }
```